# How can I set a Google Forms survey to read-only?

Tags: google-forms

I finished the collection of responses through a Google Form. Now I want to set the survey to read-only, i.e. allowing people to view the form but not submit any more responses.

Comment: Could you please have a look at [this](https://goo.gl/forms/MmjGr53MjpEn7A923) approach? Should it fit your needs I can explain further.

Comment: @marikamitsos I like it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could potentially trick the user with form data validation though its kind of mean as it would still invite them to try and answer but if you set the validation to require something totally  obscure they could never really answer it.

If you simply no longer want to receive responses you can disable them and the form will no longer accept responses. Under the Responses tab the first line "acccepting responses" click that and it will disable your form. (Users will not see it then.)

Answer (score 1):

I performed a workaround as follows:

1. Add a new title at the beginning to tell users that they can enter responses but will not be able to submit
2. Add a field at the very end: "This survey no longer allows one to submit responses" of type "Short answer text". Then set a "Data Validation" rule. I simply set "text" "contains" "a complex password". I also set the custom error message to "This field is password protected to prevent submissions". Unless someone gets your "complex password", submissions are blocked.

PS: If you have sections, with mandatory fields, the user (or reviewer) will have to enter data to proceed. You may consider making them all optional to facilitate navigation.

Comment: How is this different from @Luke of TMC's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Google Forms does not currently have this ability.